# Java BufferedReader blocks on unix pipe

Tags: java, io, pipe

I am presently facing an issue while using BufferedReader to get an handle to a unix pipe. My java application first creates the pipe, then an external perl script executed through this java application writes to this pipe and finally a Java application thread reads from this unix pipe continuously.

I am using the following code to read the unix pipe from Java. However I see that the 4th statement blocks and never returns. I am using JDK 1.8 -

```
File f = new File("/tmp/abc_c");  
System.out.println(f.exists) ;  
if (f.exists())  
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/abc_c"));
```

Also i see that sysout prints true. I wanted to know whether it is correct to use BufferedReader to read a Unix pipe?

Comment: When does it block? Before even reading anything or later on?

Comment: Before reading anything. Just while opening.

Comment: OK, and also, why do you open a reader directly? Recall that a reader will attempt to decode the byte stream into characters. That is one problem you have (and you don't specify the character coding to use as well)

Comment: This is a existing code which I was trying to debug.So does that mean that I need to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html with binary encoding as the file charset is binary?

Comment: An `InputStreamReader` may be a solution, yes; also, since you use Java 7+, consider using `Files.newInputStream()` instead of a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I noticed that the new BufferedReader was inside a while loop and after a point it showed "too many files open" exception. I have now moved it outside the while loop. Now I am facing another issue - The reader.ready() method blocks. I am still using FileReader. I will check using InputStream now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to bad code. The file reading was happening inside a while loop and it was giving too many files open message. This was fixed by moving the file open code outside the loop.